# Scrolling on website switches between sections

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

I've been trying to achieve scroll effect which changes trough sections - not move downward or upward normally but "jump" between elements.

Take an example:

```
<main>
   <section id="s1">
      ... some content
   </section>
   <section id="s2">
      ... some content
   </section>
   <section id="s3">
      ... some content
   </section>
</main>
```

So if I were to scroll down, the section 's1' would change to 's2', then 's2' would change to 's3' and so on.
I should add, every section has the same height of `100vh` and I am generally using flexbox

```
html {
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

section {
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

Should anyone have a clue how to resolve this, I would be grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to achieve the effect of scroll snap.

You'll need something like this for your css:

```css
main {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

section {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Alternatively if you want the scroll snap to be on the page.

```css
html {
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

section {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

There's some more options you can tinker with, you can get a good idea of how it works [here](https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/).

Comment: I have indeed try this approach but it does not seem to be working - my 'main' is embedded in body along other elements (nav etc.) - could this be the reason?

Comment: sorry about that, I didn't quite test the answer I gave, I edited such that it works now.